# CPU utilization reached 100% after changing OS time on SQL Server with Mirroring configured for a database

Tags: sql-server, mirroring

We have configured mirroring on SQL database server. Suddenly principal database server reached 100% CPU, windows log events shows following 2 logs

> 1. This event is generated when the system time is changed. It is
>      normal for the Windows Time Service, which runs with System
>      privilege, to change the system time on a regular basis. Other
>      system time changes may be indicative of attempts to tamper with the
>      computer.
> 2. Change Reason: An application or system component changed the time.

After that following log messages have been shown:

> 3. Database mirroring is inactive for database 'bonddickinson'. This is
>      an informational message only. No user action is required.

Does change time of OS system impacts on mirroring?

Comment: I have not seen anywhere that changing OS time would impact mirroring in such a way that CPU spikes to 100 %. Can you also read SQL Server errorlog I guess this would have more relevant information